# How to make Visual Studio Code look for dependencies in a mounted partition?

Tags: ubuntu, dependencies, visual-studio-code, singularity-container

I want to compile a large code base using Visual Studio Code but I don't want to install the dependencies (that I obtain them through `apt-get` or `pip`) of that code base on my laptop. Instead, I have installed those dependencies in another partition and have mounted that partition to my laptop

My goal is to use the CMake extension in VS Code to generate the CMake files for that code base and compile it. However, CMake gives errors as it cannot find the dependencies on my machine. So I wonder, how can I make Visual Studio Code to **only** look for dependencies in a specific location (say the mounted partition) instead of my machine?